# Variable message is string

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.io

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {

});
```

variable message is string with only user name. Things like message.content are undefined. I need more than only user name.

I've tried:

```
client.on("message", function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt)  {

});
```

but I need things like author of message or server where the message was sent.

code before this function:

```
const Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');

const Keyv = require('keyv');

var fs = require("fs");

const keyv = new Keyv();

// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot
var client = new Discord.Client({
    token: auth.token,
    autorun: true
});
client.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(client.username + ' - (' + client.id + ')');
});



process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log('Caught exception: ', err);
});
```

Comment: The question tag specifies discord.js, but you are using discord.io in your code. Is this intentional?

Comment: discord.io is not a think from discord.js?

Comment: Discord.io and Discord.js are two different libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using discord.js instead of discord.io.
discord.js has a nice API documentation pointing you at the things you probably want:

client on message event: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message
Message type properties and methods: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message

discord.io seems to be highjacking the discord name for some trivial functions. From their own site:

> Discord.io is the website that allows you to create custom, personal discord invites. A custom Discord invite is a powerful marketing tool when you use it carefully. It is not just an invite, but a medium between your member and your server. A custom Discord invite allows you to collect so much data about your members and their behaviors.

Comment: `var Discord = require('discord.js');` after this line program exits with: waiting for debugger to disconnect

Comment: I found working script which uses discord.js,problem solved

Comment: did you run `npm install discord.js` first ?

Comment: I used script: https://gist.github.com/eslachance/3349734a98d30011bb202f47342601d3

Comment: The quote you refered to is from a different service. This one is Discord.io for npm/nodejs: https://github.com/izy521/discord.io